# Parsing Excel files in monotouch

Tags: excel, xamarin.ios

Are there any good ways of parsing Excel files in monotouch? Seems like most methods to work with Excel is based on using the Excel Object Library. Doesn't seem like that's even an option in monotouch? I read that objective-c doesn't have any native support for Excel-files, so don't know if that would change anything?

Comment: You can use QuickLook which is part of iOS if all you want to do is render Excel files.

Comment: @miguel.de.icaza No, I need to parse the content, do some stuff with the data, and then display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just writing the middle step, a web service that fetches the Excel file, parses it and serves up the content as xml/json.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to either

1. write your own
2. find an obj-c library that does it and write MT bindings for it
3. find a open source .NET library and port it to MT

If all you want to do is display a file, you can use the existing iOS document APIs to do it.

The newest Office formats are XML based, so depending on how complex the files are, writing your own parser might be feasible to do.

Comment: Yeah, that's true, but it might be a bit too time consuming. We have another option, which is to create a "middle step" web service that will get the Excel file, parse it, and feed out XML... But I was hoping not to do that, just because it would be another place to write code.